# How to put Username to Codeiginiter URI Routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let say my url in codeigniter:

```
http://myurl.com/username
```

If the output will be:

```
1) http://myurl.com/username/about_us

2) http://myurl.com/username/profile

3) http://myurl.com/username/account
```

How I can located `username` like in the output?
I had research little bit in
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html but still not get right solution.

Any body can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I'll assume you are using a "User" controller your code and 
then a function for each of the view as such

```
class User extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
        }
        public function about($username)
        {
            //code here
                //load view
        }
        public function profile($username)
        {
                //code here
                //load view
        }
        public function account($username)
        {
                //code here
                //load view
        }
    }
```

Then go to your config/routes.php file and add these routes

```
$route['(:any)/about_us'] = "user/about/$1";
$route['(:any)/profile'] = "user/profile/$1";
$route['(:any)/account'] = "user/account/$1";
```

With this you can easily use $username from any of the page functions you have up there.

Answer (score 0):

try this in config/routes.php

```
$route[':any'] = "controller/function";
```

and for aboutus and other

```
$route[':any/aboutus'] = "controller/aboutus";
```

in your controller

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

to get the username

Comment: Can you tell me how to do like facebook? I mean, the username just like:
http:///facebook.com/user302/about_us ...

Comment: u have to create new column for this user302....while create the user use username and random no... or update the use after create......and combine username and id

Comment: check this may be, solve your question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157423/codeigniter-how-to-set-routes-to-default-controller-according-to-the-no-of-uri-s]